# its posible to restrict users of firebase project to edit only specific documents and collections from console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to restrict Firebase Project users from editing only specific documents and collections from the console? Hello, I am a high school teacher and I would like to teach students how to use firebase, giving them the possibility to create their own documents without being able to modify or eliminate those of their classmates. In order to avoid creating a different firebase account for each student. Another question is whether it is possible to restrict to firebase deploy functions to specific user, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user account has write access to your Firestore data, that applies to the entire database.  It can be limited once granted.  The same is true for deployment.  There are no granular user-based controls for either of these tasks.

It's generally expected that people create their own projects in order to isolate access to only themselves.